# Daily billing status for CSP plan

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

we are using a subscription bought from an CSP. and we want to know daily billing and consumption . But CSP vendor says that we have to buy a 3rd party application to get daily billing consumption. Is there any way by which we can get daily billing consumption without 3rd party tool.?

Comment: can you login the azure portal, and check it via "cost management + billing" menu?

Comment: Ask your partner to transition your Subscriptions to Azure Plan and Activate the Policy "Users in [Company Name] with access to an Azure subscription can view its charges at pay-as-you-go price." in Azure Lighthouse and you will be able to use the Cost Management to see the daily cost. But note that the daily cost is always a few days behind since MS API is built like that

Comment: @IvanYang no i don't have access to billing or cost related features.

Comment: @DanielBjörk there are few 3rd party utilites like cloudfx which are able to provide real time billing and cost info . How are they doing it ?

Comment: @GauravMoolani There is no realtime in Azure. There is always delays. Some services can have a delay of a few minutes and some have a few days. So they only way they can do it is to get the pricelist and calculate themselfs and keep track if a service is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your partner, is it a "Direct" or "Indirect".

If it is a direct partner then it has access to Azure Cost Management as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/get-started-partners), and the can enable you to see retail price consumption [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/get-started-partners#enable-the-policy-to-view-azure-usage-charges).

If it is an indirect partner then they should provide you a way to follow your consumption (through an in-house app, through a consumption export Excel file or any other communication you have agreed and signed with them as a customer).

Just as a reminder in CSP the Partner is responsible to bill accordingly and to explain your consumption, not Microsoft.